# Journey Builder : how to setup a goal on the next order?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I want to send a Journey to some contacts, and my goal is to have them buying on my website.
I have, in one Data Extension, the last order date and the total orders.

I don't see how I can say in my goal "reach the goal if an order have been done AFTER my contact enters in my journey".

I know I can "add an attribute to compare" but I don't see with what I can compare.  I thought I could compare the 'Number of orders' in my Contact Data with the 'number of orders' in my Journey Data (just checking if the first one is greater than the second, but I can't choose Journey Data in the Goal...

I hope you understand my issue, tell me if it's not clear and I'll explain again.

Thanks in advance for your help !

Kind regards,

David

Comment: I believe for this use case you would need to populate another DE which is populated using a query activity based on your criteria

Comment: Thanks ! Actually I put some 'update contacts' in my journey, and especially 1 for when the contact enters in this journey. I have 1 single DE for all my journeys. And I can't compare the value of when the contacts enters in the journey with the last_order_date as my date for when he enters in the journey might be empty for this contact (if he never enters in it). 
And because it can be empty (nullable field), I can't compare with this value...
So I guess your suggestion would be to have a specific DE, only for this journey...?

Comment: Hi @EazyE , I tried to create a specific Data Extension for this. I put the "Enter date" as a not null field but I'm facing the same issue : my field 'Last Order Date', which comes from my main data extension CAN be null, of course ! And because of that, I can't compare values ! Do you have any other idea of how I can do this check ?

Comment: in this new de the subscriber should only exist if they have an order date after entry, so it shouldn't be nullable

Comment: @EazyE thank you, I guess then my solution will come with 2 DE : one with when someone enters in my Birthday Journey, and another one with all contacts who has at least 1 order. This last one would be populated with a Query activity every hour. It seems to be the only one to have 2 non nullable fields. 
Did you imagine another solution as someone can enter in my journey without any order, and everybody does not enter in my journey ?